# SpringMVC Storing Base64

Tags: java, html, spring-mvc, base64

I have a Spring MVC application which has a registration form. This form has a picture in the format of base64 data. I would like to store this data in the database. Presently i am storing the base64 data in an input element. I have a few questions regarding this;

1. what html element should i hold the base64 data in presently i am using an input element however i am getting an error on insert (Blob is the data type used in the Database and the Java object) -

   `Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type java.sql.Blob for property photo; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.sql.Blob] for property photo: no matching editors or conversion strategy found`

   OR is there a way to convert String To BLOB in java
2. Do i still need to use  enctype="multipart/form-data" on the form tag even thought the data is in base64?
3. If the base64 data is stored in held in html file element how do i preform validation on that to check if it is NULL?

Comment: Check this, if it help - http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-file-upload-example/

Comment: @Vinit Prajapati this uses a file object i would liek to know if it works the same way for base64 encoded data. It doesn't show the html element that holds the base64 value. It also doesn't show how the data reaches a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LobHelper` to convert it to a `Blob`. You get the LobHelper from your hibernate session `Session.getLobHelper()`.

As long as you don't have an `<input type="file" />`, there should be no need for enctype="multipart/form-data".

Validation should work as on ordinary String properties with @NotNull.

Personally I wouldn't store it encoded.

Comment: is there any other way to do the blob conversion if i am not using hibernate or will this work regardless

Answer (score 1):

You might have put the `path` of the Blob e.g. `<form:input path="theBlobField">` without adding a `PropertyEditor` for Blobs in your `initBinder`,

which means, you're trying to directly store a value of String type to Blob type - voila! IllegalStateException.

Possible approach is to create a `PropertyEditor` that converts your Base64 encoded String to a Blob type.

To decode the encoded String, you can use appache commons' `Base64.decodeBase64` which returns an array of bytes then do your magic converting those bytes to Blob

Another solution is to forget about the path, use a simple `<input name="photoData">` tag, then at the backend, just use `request.getParameter("photoData")` which gets the base64 encoded String data

One more thing, if things don't work, well maybe the encoded data starts with a `mimeType` declaration. To remove it use

```
//@RequestParam data
//remove mimeType declaration in the data string first
String byteStr = data.split(",")[1];


//get the byte array of the data
byte[] bytes = Base64.decodeBase64(byteStr);
```